# Double nesting a function-valued return stops from entering the double nested function

Tags: javascript, return, scope-chain

Trying to understand the *scope chain* and *execution context stack* articles from [David Shariff's Blog](http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-scope-chain-and-closures/), I've tried to understand closures here

```
function foo() {
    var a = 'private variable';
    return function bar() {
        alert(a);
    }
}

var callAlert = foo();
callAlert(); // private variable
```

I just wanted to test if inner function has the *variable object* just from its parent or from the whole scope chain, so I added a nested function repeating the example:

```
function foo() {
    var a = 'private variable';
    return function bar() {
        return function foobar() {
            console.log(a);
        };
    };
}

var callAlert = foo();
callAlert();  //
```

And that is not giving any result. It seems the interpreter is not even entering the *foobar()* function. And the syntax is the same than its parent.

But it works if I divide the function declaration and execution.

```
function foo() {
    var a = 'private variable';
    return function bar() {
        function ra() {
            console.log(a);
        };
        return ra();
    };
}

var callAlert = foo();
callAlert(); // private variable
```

And really I'm trying to guess why; where's the difference from *bar()* and *foobar()* functions.

PS - I'm testing on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: the first `bar` returns a function (that you never execute, which is why you see nothing), while the second returns the *result* of executing `ra`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function foo() {
    var a = 'private variable';
    return function bar() {
        return function foobar() {
            console.log(a);
        };
    };
}
```

Here you're returning a function that returns a function, so you need to call that new, doubly nested function

```
var callAlert = foo()();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LxSg6/)

Or any variation on that theme

```
var getBar = foo();
var getFooBar = getBar();
getFooBar(); //private variable.
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LxSg6/1/)

---

The second example works fine because you're still returning **one function**—a function that simple calls another function.

```
return function bar() {
    function ra() {
        console.log(a);
    };
    return ra();
};
```

Comment: thanks, that's interesting!
So I was not calling the *foobar()* function.

Is there any article where I can understand better why the interpreter is not executing the function while calling the *return*?

Comment: @Pictor - sorry, I missed this comment.  Umm, not really.  Just remember that functions are first class citizens in JavaScript.  You can pass them into, and return them from other functions.  So when you say  return function(){} you're returning a function, just like that.  It's no different from saying return 0;  The 0 isn't getting executed any more than the function; both are simply being returned as is.