# returning value from double-nested function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i am trying to get a simple value from my node server like so:

```
getNodeServerValue = function()      {
    return io.socket.emit('server-Query', 
         function(data) {
               console.log('data is now: ' + data);  // works fine!
               return (data);
         }
   );
}
```

and i wish to be able retrieve the value like this:

```
var myReturnedValue = getNodeServerValue();
```

but *returnedValue* contains the function itself, and not the value being returned.  and getNodeServerValue()() did not work either.

i have attempted returning a variable, setTimeout, clearTimeout, etc.  with no success because of the async nature of jScript.

this example is loosely based on the "Sending and getting data (acknowledgements" example in the [socket.io docs.](http://socket.io/docs/)

looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373934/returning-values-from-nested-functions-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502954/double-nesting-a-function-valued-return-stops-from-entering-the-double-nested-fu) didn't help me since my requirements are double nested, and also i need to name the **getNodeServerValue** with a variable.

i am sure this is an easy question, so please dont down-vote me without an explanation.

thank you very much.

Comment: you can´t return the data because it will not be available by the time your function returns. You need to use callbacks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: You should use promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a promise library, or if in Node they are supported natively

```
io.getNodeServerValue = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  io.socket.emit('server-Query', 
         function(data) {
               resolve(data);
         }
   );
});
```

use it like so:

```
io.getNodeServerValue.then(function (data) {
  // data is here!
});
```

Comment: your suggested solution will "initialize" when the node client first connects, but  the function does not execute after that.   is there a way to make sure that the function runs every time, and not just when the socket connects?